# Connecting to SQL Server in R with ODBC package to a non-default port

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, port

I'm trying to connect through Rstudio standard ODBC package with driver "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" to a remote SQL Server running on non-default port, but I always get a timeout. The credentials are correct, as I can connect through a different client.

Following guides on https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/214510788-Setting-up-R-to-connect-to-SQL-Server-

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                 Server = "mysqlhost",
                 Database = "mydbname",
                 UID = "myuser",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
                 Port = 21433)
```

Unfortunately none of the package documentation deals with connecting to a non-default port and just changing the Port parameter doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to a non-default port, you will need to add the correct port number both in **Port** parameter, but ALSO in the **Server** separated by coma

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                 Server = "mysqlhost,21433"
                 Database = "mydbname",
                 UID = "myuser",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
                 Port = 21433)
```

This allows you to connect to the server.